# Find the conditional distribution ,which probably is binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Sheila has a coin with $P(head)= p_1$ and betty has a coin with $P(head) = p_2$.Sheila tosses her coin $m$ times. Each time she obtains heads , betty tosses her coin(otherwise not). Find the distribution of the total number of heads obtained by betty.

If we let $N$ be the number of heads obtained by Sheila and $X$ the number of heads obtained by Betty, then we have the following model:

$X\mid N = n \enspace \in \enspace Bin(n,p_2)$, with $N \enspace \in \enspace Bin(m,p_1)$

Now the $E [X]$ i found to be $mp_1p_2$ and $Var[X] = mp_1p_2(1-p_1p_2)$ so this seem to be a binomial distribution $Bin(m,p_1p_2)$

however,

$P[X=k]  = \sum\limits_{n=k}^{m} P(x= k\mid N = n)P(N =n) = \sum\limits_{n=k}^{m} \binom{n}{k}p_2^kq_2^{n-k} \binom{m}{n}p_1^nq_1^{m-n}$

the question is how do you arrange the factors so that one can see that it is a $Bin(m,p_1p_2)$ distribution - assuming that is really the  distribution

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is binomial. For $i=1$ to $m$, let $X_i=1$ if Betty gets a head after the $i$-th toss by Sheila, anf let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

The probability that $X_i=1$ is $p_1p_2$. The total number $X$ of heads by Betty is the sum $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_m$. This is a sum of independent Bernoulli random variables with probability of success $p_1p_2$, so it has binomial distribution with parameters $m$ and $p_1p_2$.

More informally, the probability of head by Betty after the toss by Sheila is $p_1p_2$, for Betty gets a head if and only if Sheila gets head on that throw **and** Betty succeeds on her then allowed throw. So on any of the $m$ trials, Betty's probability of success is $p_1p_2$, and there are $m$ independent trials.